# MS PowerPoint export as PDF makes lines thick (Mac)

Tags: macos, pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

I found a problem in exporting PowerPoint files into PDF on my Mac (macOS High Sierra 10.13.5 and PowerPoint 16.14.1). Boxes with borders of 1pt thickness are displayed much thicker in the exported PDF. This is a huge problem for me since this makes charts look ugly.

This is the screenshot inside of Powerpoint of two boxes with 1pt border:

[image: Screenshot inside Powerpoint]

This is the screenshot of the exported PDF (save as PDF):

[image: Screenshot of the exported PDF]

I tried PDFWriter and other tools and didn't find any solution. **Is this a bug and is there a solution to it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems (by looking at the current slow beta version) that this is solved in PowerPoint version 16.15 for Mac. So the **solution** for now: **update to version 16.15**.

Comment: Or roll back to an earlier version pre-the update that caused the problem.  If you look in the PowerPoint section of MS Answers, there are a zillion complaints about this update and printing/PDF creation. At least a couple of them have answers explaining how to roll back to a previous version.